# Mapbox-gl animate markers

Tags: animation, npm, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I've been reading the documentation on MapboxGL marker animation, but all resources reference markers that are added as a layer. I'd like to set it so that when a user clicks a specific marker, it either changes color or gets larger.

I'm adding the markers in using the mapbox-gl npm pacakage, so my markers look like:

```
createMarker = (latLng, popup) => {
    marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color: '#40798C'})
    .setLngLat(latLng)
    .setPopup(popup)
    .addTo(map)
    this.updateMarkerArr(marker)
  }
```

You can see the full repo here (https://github.com/ashleighc207/react-neighborhood-map) for context or to test yourself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mapbox GL JS Marker is just an [HTML ELement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) so you can detect hover or click with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and then modify the style (for size or color) with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS).